# Whether point is in a polygon or not in mongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I have a mongodb database containing latitudes and longitudes of the form:
e.g {a:1,latitude:1.0,longitude:2.0,b:2}, etc.
I wish to check whether the latitude longitude pair exits in coordinate or not.

I have queried for the document in

```
collecton = db['DbName']
cursor = collection.find()
for doc in cursor:  
    collection.find({"LondonCoordinates":{"$geoIntersects":{"$geometry":{"type":"Point", "coordinates":[longitude1, latitude1]}}}}
```

as well as:

```
for doc in cursor: 
    collection.find({loc: {$geoWithin: {$geometry: {type : "Polygon" ,coordinates: [[[ -0.5103750999999999, 51.286760199999996], [ -0.5103750999999999, 51.6918741],[ 0.33401549999999997, 51.6918741],[ 0.33401549999999997, 51.286760199999996], [ -0.5103750999999999, 51.286760199999996]]]}}}})
```

These don't seem to work. What I want is a true/false value whether [doc["Longitude"],doc["Latitude"]] exist in the polygon or not.